# Include last line of a text file in a Powershell email

Tags: windows, powershell, email, gmail, scheduled-tasks

I have setup a windows scheduled task to send me an email at a certain time of the day using this command

> PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\email.ps1

And in the email.ps1 file is

```
$Username = "senderusername_without @gmail.com";
$Password = "gmailpassword";
$path = "C:\Dial Engine Pro\out.txt";

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string]$attachmentpath){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "senderemail@gmail.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "Dial Engine Pro outgoing call log $(get-date)";
    $message.Body = "Hi, this is your automated Dial Engine Pro outgoing call logs delivery. `n `n";
    $attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentpath);
    $message.Attachments.Add($attachment);

    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message);
    $attachment.Dispose();
 }
Send-ToEmail  -email "myemail@gamil.com" -attachmentpath $path;
```

The text file looks like this

> "No Name","*210755123456#","2018-12-19 14:00:33","","Line has disconnected. --> Connection is terminated by the other side.","","28"
>   "No Name","*210755654321#","2018-12-19 18:00:33","","Line has disconnected. --> Connection is terminated by the other side.","","27"
>   "No Name","#21#","2018-12-19 21:00:14","","Line has disconnected. --> Connection is terminated by the other side.","","9"

How can I change the body of the email to also include the last line of the text file instead of attaching it? It would be nice if I could use the values of the text file like Last line "value of what's in quote" 2 and "" and "value of what's in quote" 5, if you get what I mean, so the email body is like "Hi, this is your automated Dial Engine Pro outgoing call logs delivery. Phone diverted to *21xxxxxxxxxx# at 18:00 with result "Line has disconnected. --> Connection is terminated by the other side."

> $message.Body = "Hi, this is your automated Dial Engine Pro outgoing call logs delivery. `n`n";

I tried various iterations of

> $message.Body = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\AACSO PC2\AppData\Roaming\Dial Engine Pro\out.txt | out-string;

But that didn't work. And I would like the email body to only contain the last line of the text file.

Here is some background on why I am doing this for those interested.
I volunteer for a helpline that's part of a worldwide fellowship and we have small office with a phone line. When someone calls the national number, if they are in my area the phone call comes to me. That part of the process is managed in Sydney at the head office. When the office is unmanned we set the phone divert by dealing *21xxxxxxxxxx# to divert the phone away from the office to a volunteer. In September 2018 our phone provider removed the ability to remote access the phone line from out of the office https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/News-Feed/Telstra-Home-Phone-Features-Exit/ba-p/747300, we have to be physically in the office to make the divert, so one volunteer was stuck receiving phone calls all night instead of them taking 4 hour shifts and passing it to the next person.

I setup a dialup modem and some software from the internet [Dial Engine Pro](http://www.phonedialerpro.com) and a few windows scheduled tasks to pickup the phone line, dial a number at a specific time and divert to a volunteer and this is making the diverts work perfectly. The program outputs a log file "out.txt". An I wanted an email with the log file so I can see if the diverts worked over night. I used a scheduled task and Powershell to make that work from a gmail account, but for that to work I had to change the gmail configuration before I could send emails from Powershell. I had to enable "less secure apps" in the google security control panel here [Google security settings](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web) and make sure 2-factor authentication was disabled.

So that's all going great with the Powershell script above I get an email with the attached log file, but I am an amateur coder and would like the email body to contain the last line of the log file rather than the whole attachment or for the email body to read nicly like

Hi,

This is your automated Dial Engine Pro outgoing call logs delivery. Phone diverted to *21xxxxxxxxxx# at 18:00 with result "Line has disconnected. --> Connection is terminated by the other side."

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at the `-Tail` parameter of `Get-Content`. if you give it a `1`, then you will get the last line from the file. [*grin*]

Comment: Great thanks. Now I jest need to get the text file into the body. Nothing I tried worked.

Comment: you are quite welcome! ///// have you tried adding the new info to the string you use for the `$message.Body` value? perhaps build the string in advance and then assign it. ///// as an aside, is there a reason you can't use the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet?

Comment: I just googled around until I found a Powershell email code that worked, this one was the best when I looked around for how to add an attachment to a Powershell email. I tried replacing what worked with  '$message.Body = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\AACSO PC2\AppData\Roaming\Dial Engine Pro\out.txt | out-string;' but that didn't work, there is nothing in the email body when I receive it.

Comment: This worked $message.Body = "Hi, this is your automated Dial Engine Pro outgoing call logs delivery. `n `n $(Get-Content $path) `n `n"; but I get all the file in a clump no lines for each line of the text file, and I only want the last line.I will try you -Tail thing.

Comment: `$message.Body = "Hi, this is your automated Dial Engine Pro outgoing call logs delivery. `n `n $(Get-Content -Tail 1 $path) `n `n";`      That worked Amazing **pikachu with mouth open in amazement** If I want to just take the contents of the 2nd "" and the 5th "" and put that into an email, is that asking too much?

Comment: you CAN build the entire text for the `.Body()` stuff ahead of time. [*grin*] build it all into a here-string or a multiline string and THEN add that to the `.Body()`.

Comment: I fund a link but it didn't work in Powershell [https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html] I tried `$String="This is a string of words."

read -r -a Words <<< "$String"

$body = "First word in String is: ${Words[0]}"`

Comment: Not sure ill worry, Thsnks for your time @Lee_Dailey

Comment: you can add another line to a single- or multi-line string by adding `[environment]::NewLine` and then the next line of text to the string. ///// in any case, good luck! [*grin*]